# Change stylesheet using npm command

Tags: angular, npm, sass, webpack-2

I have 2 style sheets, Example, S1.scss and S2.scss . I need to use S1.scss for client 1 and other for client 2. How can I achieve that using npm commands while building the application or may be with npm start? I have **Webpack** 2 to build the app.

Comment: You might use `configuration` flag maybe: [https://angular.io/cli/build](https://angular.io/cli/build)

Comment: i don't think you can achieve that with npm command.  All your styles are imported in the styles.scss and then in angular.json you have `"styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],` . The solution i think it's more complicated than running a npm command. maybe you will find your answer here : https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4202. Or maybe with `configuration` as stated in the above comment

Comment: @TheParam afaik, you cannot use comments in `angular.json` as JSON must be totally valid and there is no such thing as `comment` in JSON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Angular CLI**

Inside the `angular.json` file you could add an extra configuration for this. This configuration would do file replacements for specific files (in your case the stylesheet files).

Here is an example configuration which can be added into the `build/configurations` node of the `angular.json` file:

```
                        "productionForClient1": {
                            "fileReplacements": [
                                {
                                    "replace": "src/styles.less",
                                    "with": "src/client1_styles.less"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
```

Then from console you should be able to build it with the styles specific to a client by running it with the configuration file for that customer:
`ng build -c productionForClient1`. If you want to run it via npm then add it as a task into your `package.json` file

---

**Webpack**

Using Webpack directly to build your Angular app you should be able to take a similar approach using the [NormalModuleReplacementPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/normal-module-replacement-plugin/).

Comment: any idea about how can I use same solution in webpack V2?

Comment: Are you using webpack v2 via an older version of angular cli (if so , which version). Or are you using webpack v2 directly to build your angular app?

Comment: I am using webpack directly to build the app instead of using cli.

Comment: I added some information regarding a solution using only Webpack. Hope it helps you out, good luck!